# VBA Regular Expression with exclusion

Tags: regex, vba, expression

I am looking for RegExp that matches something like the following:

25+ 1.25+ (any numeric format with plus sign to the right - no space between)

but does not match the following:
"25+" "1.25+" (any numeric format with plus sign to the right - no space between but within double quotes)

ThanKs

Comment: What pattern do you have so far?

Comment: Thanks. I have the following: ([.01-9]+\+)

Comment: ^(?!\"[0.1-9]+\+\")([0.01-9]+\+) but does not match 1.25+

Comment: can you share you vba code?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/OEPWHB/1

Comment: It is a simple match and replace function

Comment: I got it: thanks everyone for the help.   ​(?![\"])([0.1-9]+\+)(?![\"])

Answer (score 0):

I got it: thanks everyone for the help.

This regexp seems to work:

​`(?![\"])([0.1-9]+\\+)(?![\"])`